# Auth Issue when upgrading from Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have following the official guide to upgrade from `laravel 5.2` to `laravel 5.3`:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

Because I needed some customizations to the default authentication I have copied the `login` function to `Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php`.

Now, when I updated, the `AuthController.php' was divided into several other files.

I have copied the `login` function to `Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

Now, I am getting the following error when trying to login:

> BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 82:
>
> Method [getCredentials] does not exist.

The login functions below (Might not matter):

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required|email', 
    'password' => 'required',
]);

$credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

// This section is the only change
if (Auth::validate($credentials)) {
    $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();
    if ($user->active) {
        Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));

        ActivityLog::add("User has successfully logged in.", $user->id);

        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    } else {
        return redirect($this->loginPath) // Change this to redirect elsewhere
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'active' => 'This account has been suspended.'
            ]);
    }
}

return redirect($this->loginPath)
    ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
    ->withErrors([
        'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
    ]);

}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where is the `getCredentials` method? It says it can't find it

Comment: Well, probably this method was removed between `5.2` and `5.3`. Or replaced with something else...

Comment: So you didn't create it? Because the error clearly states that your code requires it, and you're using it here `$credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method simply returns the login username (which can be username, email or custom field) and the password from the request data. You can replace the `getCredentials()` call with this:

```
$request->only($this->username(), 'password');
```

**NOTE**

depending on how you merged the code, the method `$this->username()` can be also used as `$this->loginUsername()` in the older version.

Comment: `Method [loginUsername] does not exist.` the method with `$this->username()` did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else looking here now the call `getCredentials(Response $response)` was replaced in 5.3 with `credentials(Response $response)`